# PHP check if value is one of other numbers in loop

Tags: php

If i have a loop for example

```
for ($a=1; $a<6; $a++)
```

Is it possible to say for the first loop if another variable like `$b` is the same as one of the other numbers that will come like `2, 3, 4 or 5`.

And what if i have a word split, so every letter is a variable like this:

```
$letter1 = str_split($word)[0];
$letter2 = str_split($word)[1];
$letter3 = str_split($word)[2];
$letter4 = str_split($word)[3];
$letter5 = str_split($word)[4];
```

How can i check if `$a` is at 1 in the loop,if it is not letter1 but letter2, 3, 4 or 5?

Comment: **Where is your code?** What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, do please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better idea of how SO works.

Comment: Have a look at `in_array()` http://php.net/in_array

Comment: May be just me, but I don't get the question. Please clarify and elaborate.

Comment: `for ($a=1; $a<6; $a++) { if ($a == $b) { echo "I am the same"; }`

Answer (score 1):

sure. Just check it against the counter:

```
for ($a=1; $a<6; $a++){
   if ($a===$b){
       echo ("b is caught!");
       break;
   }
}
```